# How do I compare effectiveness of different linear regression models

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I have a dataframe which contains three more or less significant correlations between target column and other columns ( LinarRegressionModel.coef_ from sklearn shows 57, 97 and 79). And I don't know what exact model to choose: should I use only most correlated column for regression or use regression with all three predictors. Is there any way to compare models effectiveness? Sorry, I'm very new to data analysis, I couldn't google any tools for this task

Comment: This will most likely either going to get ignored or closed for too broad. You should migrate this question to the cross validated community and try to be more specific. There are a number of ways that you can compare the effectiveness of different linear regression models, but it is impossible to answer without knowing what you are trying to do. Also try searching for feature selection, which is the process of selecting features to use as inputs for models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first at all, you must know that when we are choosing the best model to apply to new data, we are going to choose the best model to fit `out of sample` data, which is the kind of samples that might are not present in the training process, after all, you want to predict new probabilities or cases. In your case, predict a new number.

So, how can we do this? Well, the best is to use metrics which can help us to choose which model is better for our dataset.

There are so many kinds of metrics for regression:

- **MAE**: Mean absolute error is the mean of the absolute value of the errors. This is the easiest of the metrics to understand since it’s just the average error.
- **MSE**: Mean squared error is the mean of the squared error. It’s more popular than a mean absolute error because the focus is geared more towards large errors.
- **RMSE**: Root means the squared error is the square root of the mean squared error. This is one of the most popular of the evaluation metrics because root means the squared error is interpretable in the same units as the response vector or y units, making it easy to relate its information.
- **RAE**: Relative absolute error, also known as the residual sum of a square, where y bar is a mean value of y, takes the total absolute error and normalizes it by dividing by the total absolute error of the simple predictor.

You can work with any of these, but I highly recommend to use **MSE** and **RMSE**.

Comment: Thank you! Embedded Scikit MSE really helps